# how to use progress with Asynctask get method?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to use progress bar... but As I searched, progress bar can not use with Asynctask.get.But I have to use .get and progress in Asynctask.

I made very simple source.
How can I changed to show progress bar in main thread??

I want to use both get method and ui progress.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AAA asyncTask = new AAA();
            try {
                ((AAA) asyncTask).execute(null, null, null,null).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public class AAA extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Object> {
    private ProgressDialog progDailog = null;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progDailog = new ProgressDialog(ViewTestActivity.this);
        progDailog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progDailog.setCancelable(true);
        progDailog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        progDailog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it before calling `AsyncTask`

```
private ProgressDialog progDailog = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AAA asyncTask = new AAA();
            try {
                progDailog = new ProgressDialog(ViewTestActivity.this);
                progDailog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progDailog.setCancelable(true);
                progDailog.show();
                ((AAA) asyncTask).execute(null, null, null,null);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public class AAA extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Object> {



    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        progDailog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an bug(?), it works well in 3000 seconds, but if i add 10000, It is not working well..T_T

Comment: When you are using get, using Async Task doesn't make any sense. Because get() will block the UI Thread. Don't use get()

Comment: ah~~~ got ya... Thanks T_T... there is no way to mix it... lol
so, i did like this:
   Upload upload = new Upload(CreateConsentNote.this);
   upload.execute(arrHash);
   arrDocURL = upload.getUploadResult();

but, 3 line don`t wait 2nd aysnctask line... haha coud u give me hint..?

Comment: upload.getUploadResult(); in onPostExecute()

Comment: that is nice idea. but .. hm.. okay!! last question!!! I`m really thanks to ur answer!! anyway, asynctask is only for asynchronous?? can i change asynctask from asynchronous to synchronous ?? if it can not be, the callback method is best(or only) way. lol

Comment: Basically asyntask is to do stuff in the background so do not have much sense in a synchronous way. If you want to do it synchronous just run it in the main thread whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thanks!!! I will try!! u save a lot of my time. haha and I got much information to u. really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a standard answer, but I've just done something very similar by setting up  listener on the main thread, and sending progress messages to the listener from the async task - actually in my case it was loading asynchronously from a database. Works fine for me.

Comment: ho?? u mean.. like callback function?

Answer (score 0):

you should update your progress bar percentage in [onProgressUpdate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...))

See this example  [AsyncTask with progress bar](http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-asynctask-example-with-progress-bar)

Comment: I think, you intend to say progress dialog, not progress bar. That's why, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: ah Thanks. i missed it... progress dialog, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
private ProgressDialog progDailog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        progDailog = new ProgressDialog(ViewTestActivity.this);
        progDailog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progDailog.setCancelable(true);
        progDailog.show();
        AAA asyncTask = new AAA(progDialog);
        try {
        ((AAA) asyncTask).execute(null, null, null,null).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        });
        }
public class AAA extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Object> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public AAA (ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```